# How to know which button is clicked in wpf button created programatically using c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, buttonclick

I am under a situation where i have to click the button which are created dynamically with programming in c# (because user decides at run time how many button to be created).
I do so by writing code like this:

```
int runTimeIntegerValue = 6; //Lets say its 6
Button[] childGridSavebutn = new Button[runTimeIntegerValue -1];
for (int j = 0; j < runTimeIntegerValue; j++)
{   
    childGridSavebutn[j] = GenerateButton("Save Table");
    childSmallgrid[j] = generateRowColumnGrid(1, 1);
    Grid.SetColumn(childGridSavebutn[j], 1);
    Grid.SetRow(childGridSavebutn[j], i);
    childSmallgrid[j].Children.Add(childGridSavebutn[j]);

    childGridSavebutn[j].Click += (source, e) =>
    {
        txtBoxOrder[j].Text = "I am from " + j;
        MessageBox.Show("I am from " + j);  //This message always show "I am From 5"
    };

}
private Button GenerateButton(string p)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    //btn.Name = p;
    btn.Content = p;
    btn.Width = 80;
    btn.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    btn.Height = 20;           
    return btn;
}
```

After I popup a message `MessageBox.Show("I am from " + i);`  to know the message box is popuped from which button . It always popups 5 (as last count of i is 5).

So How to know which button is clicked, by click on that button? As there are 5 buttons, so i should know by click on the button that button number 1/2/3/4/5 is clocked by pop up of message with respected i position. 
(I mean button at ith position is clicked, and message must show this the "I am from 2" when 2nd button is clicked)

**SUMMARY: I have childGridSavebutn[1 to 5] array (it could be even 10 decided run time by user). And it display 5 buttons, How to know which button is clicked ? (as it always popups 5th one) because further i have to generate button click events receptively. How will i do that if i do not know which button is clicked.**  At last UI has to repeat like this 5 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
childGridSavebutn[i].Click += (source, e) =>
{    
    txtBoxOrder[i].Text = "I am from " + i;
    MessageBox.Show("I am from " + i);  //This message always show "I am From 5"
};
```

with

```
childGridSavebutn[i].Tag = i;
childGridSavebutn[i].Click += (source, e) =>
{
    var button = source as Button;
    var index = (int)button.Tag;
    txtBoxOrder[index].Text = "I am from " + index;
    MessageBox.Show("I am from " + index);
};
```

You must need to set the the value of `i` while subscribing the event, you can use `Tag` property for this. Otherwise you will get the last updated value of `i` on every message.

Comment: ^the above code simply corrects the given code (y) :)

Answer (score 4):

EDIT 2:
What you asked for in the comments

```
<Grid Name="ButtonsContainer">
    <ListBox Name="lb_GlobalList">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Tag="{Binding SomeNumberValue}" Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeNumberValue, StringFormat={}I am from {0}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<SomeBusinessObject> businessObjects = new List<SomeBusinessObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            businessObjects.Add(new SomeBusinessObject() { SomeNumberValue = i, SomeTextValue = "sample text" });
        }
        lb_GlobalList.ItemsSource = businessObjects;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am from " + (sender as Button).Tag.ToString());
    }
}

public class SomeBusinessObject
{
    public int SomeNumberValue { get; set; }
    public string SomeTextValue { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
I am not using your code on purpose so you will understand:

1. Capture variables in closured
2. How to use controls without `Name` property in a proper way (sender object in the event)
3. How to store any object using the `Tag` property - even other controls
4. That what you are doing is wrong on so many levels - DataBindig, DataTemplate etc. as commented in other answer

In my opinion the best solutions is to add some metadata you want to associate with your `Button` class using `Tag` and then add Click event the usual way and use
`(sender as Button)` in the event handler to access the button

see my example

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Tag = i;
        b.Click += B_Click;
        sp_Container.Children.Add(b);
    }
}

private void B_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((sender as Button).Tag.ToString());
}
```

ALSO in my opinion what you are doing is wrong. You shoud be needing this example rather in special cases. You have the DataBinding ability in WPF, use it!

Comment: I found at last you binding is not correct. But still thanks for giving me direction.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you **need** to create these buttons programatically? Consider approach of generating buttons purely in XAML basing on your view models.

Suppose you hava a view model for single button:

```
public class SingleButtonViewModel {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

Your parent view model:

```
public class ParentViewModel {
    public IList<SingleButtonViewModel> Buttons { get; set; }
}
```

And in your XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Text}" Command="{Binding Command}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then you create your button view models programmaticaly, give it any command you want.

Consider, that I was not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and so for the sake of readibility.

Comment: Thats not a problem, you can style it as you like.

Comment: And how you will repeat the view number of times ? And it must update the button which clicked (and also textbox in which the user writtes text). How to do that ? (I mean this UI generationa nd its reptition) . Please help me, i am badly stuck since 2 weeks on it.

Comment: This is DataTemplate used to define how to show element of the collection. Collections are usually used to store more than one element. So I don't understand this "not just one button" remark. This man is trying to help you. Try give him some respect by trying to understand what he wrote. To update TextBox accordingly you can use relative Binding (ElementName=...)

Comment: You have to create List<Button> variable, add all created buttons to the list. Assign this list as an ItemSource of the container control, and use Appropriate data template. Then you can even go deeper and nest the datatemplates or use Binding ElementName and use "TextBox and Button" as represtentation of the object

Comment: If you don't understand very nice example he provided see this http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html it is in tutorial form, maybe it will be easier for you to understand

Comment: @Peuczyński I will really thankyou if you could please give me an example repeating a grid 2 times and grid will contain a textbox and button. And it would be great help for me. I will immedaitely mark you as answer.. And will implement in my project (it's bigger scenario  in my project)

Comment: I will update my answer with the snipper you want in a few minutes

Comment: Ok sure.Thanyou so much.. I am waiting :) It would be a great help for me. After that i will implement that in my big project. But remember this grid which repeat 2 (it would be many in my case as user will decide at runtime) times contains 1 textbox and button .On launching code when 2nd grid button is clicked it must update something in second textbox.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your code to.

```
for (int jj = 0; jj < runTimeIntegerValue; jj++)
{   
    int j = jj;
    some code as you had before    
}
```

The problem you are getting is due to how C# captured variables in closures.

Eric Lippert has an in-depth explanation of this behaviour:

- [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)
- [Closing over the loop variable, part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx)

Basically, it's the loop variable that is captured, not it's value.

---

**Everyone hits this issue with captured variables at least once, and if you don't know what it is, you can't google for the solution.**

Using `Tag` as in other answers is also a valid solution.   Likewise using a data binding template, may be the best solution.    *Hence I am not voting to close this as a duplicate of one of the 101 questions on captured variables in closures.*

Comment: This answer get's to the root cause of the problem (without judging whether you actually want to do this in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

When your current code gets a button click the value of `j` has completed the loop so for all button clicks you get the last value of `j`.

But it's easy to fix. Just change your loop like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < runTimeIntegerValue; j++)
{
    childGridSavebutn[j] = GenerateButton("Save Table");
    childSmallgrid[j] = generateRowColumnGrid(1, 1);
    Grid.SetColumn(childGridSavebutn[j], 1);
    Grid.SetRow(childGridSavebutn[j], i);
    childSmallgrid[j].Children.Add(childGridSavebutn[j]);

    childGridSavebutn[j].Click += (source, e) =>
    {
        int j2 = j;
        txtBoxOrder[j2].Text = "I am from " + j2;
        MessageBox.Show("I am from " + j2);
    };
}
```

The line `int j2 = j;` captures the value of `j` at the time the loop is run so that `j2` is correct when the click occurs.

Comment: @Eniggmativity Ok thanks but please see this question. Because even if it works then also it is not MVVM approach. So please see my another question where i am trying to do the same with MVVM approach but binding error is coming in ItemSource : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671241/does-not-contain-a-definition-for-itemssource-and-no-extension-method-itemsso?noredirect=1#comment53190648_32671241